# How to pass multiple inputs into a single query?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sql

In my app I want the user to mention how many columns he wants for the table and then enter the data for those columns and create a table with those values.
Here is what I have:

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <label for="numOfCols">Enter Number of Fields</label>
    <input name="numOfCols" type="number" id="numOfCols">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="numOfColsSubmit" >Generate</button>

</form>

<?php if(isset($_POST["numOfCols"])): ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="tbName">Enter Layout Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="tbName" id="tbName" class="form-control">

<?php $numOfCols = $_POST["numOfCols"];
for ($colNum = 0 ; $colNum < $numOfCols ; $colNum++): ?>

    <div class="row g-4">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <label for="col_name<?php $colNum ?>">Name</label><br>
            <input class="form-control" id="col_name<?php $colNum ?>" type="text"  
             name="col_name<?php $colNum ?>" >
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm">
            <label for="col_types<?php $colNum ?>">Type</label><br>
            <select  name="col_types<?php $colNum ?>" class="form-control" id="col_types<?php $colNum ?>">
                <option value="int">INT</option>
                <option value="varchar" >VARCHAR</option>
                <option value="text">TEXT</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
            <label for="col_length<?php $colNum ?>">Length</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="col_length<?php $colNum ?>" id="col_length<?php $colNum ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
            <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitaddcol<?php $colNum ?>">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    


<?php endfor; ?>
    <button type="submit" name="createtb" class="btn">Create Layout</button>
</form>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if(isset($_POST["tbName"])){
        $table->createTb($_POST['tbName']);
    } ?>
```

and the function for creating the table :

```
function createTb($tb){

    $arr = [];

    if(isset($_POST['col_name'])){
        $colName = $_POST['col_name'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['col_types'])){
        $colTypes = $_POST['col_types'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['col_length'])){
        $colLength = $_POST['col_length'];
    }
    echo $tb;

    array_push($arr , $colName , $colTypes , $colLength);


    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE $tb ($colName $colTypes($colLength)) ");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['name'], 29]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = null;


}
```

I was thinking of getting the data from the user, pass it to an array and then use that array in my query.
The problem is I cannot get all of the user data. If the user has 2 or more columns, it will always get the last column. Any insight?

(Putting the createTb($_POST['tbName']) inside the for loop for some reason results in now showing or calling the function at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your input-fields as an array like:
`<input type="text" name="col_name[]" value="foo" />`
And get it with `var_dump($_POST['col_name']);`

In your example you could do like this:

```
<?php $numOfCols = $_POST["numOfCols"];
for ($colNum = 0 ; $colNum < $numOfCols ; $colNum++): ?>
   <input class="form-control" id="col_name_<?=$colNum ?>" type="text" name="col_name[<?=$colNum ?>]" >
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="col_length[<?= $colNum ?>]" id="col_length_<?=$colNum ?>">
<?php endfor; ?>
```

And get the result:

```
if(isset($_POST['col_name']) && is_array($_POST['col_name'])) {
   for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['col_name']); $i++) {
       var_dump($_POST['col_name'][$i]);
       var_dump($_POST['col_length'][$i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Fixed a bug `<?php $colNum; ?>` to <?=$colNum;?>